# How to get the maximum or minimum (whichever is applicable) values of this function?

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

In my Physics Textbook, I've been asked to denote the maximum or minimum value of this function (whichever is applicable):

$$x(t) = x_0(1 - e^{-\gamma t}), \text{where } t \ge 0, x_0 > 0$$

Now, I tried to do it like this.

First, I tried to find a point in the graph of the function which has the slope $0$. My logic is the maxima or minima, both of the points have slope $0$, so by trying to equate the derivative w.r.t $t$ with $0$, we can have the corresponding value for t.

But, I failed, horribly so.

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}[x_0(1 - e^{-\gamma t})]$$

$$= x_0\frac{d}{dt}(1 - e^{-\gamma t})$$

$$= x_0[-e^{-\gamma t} * \frac{d}{dt}(-\gamma t)]$$

$$= x_0(-e^{-\gamma t} * -\gamma) = \gamma x_0e^{-\gamma t}$$

Trying to equate this with $0$,

$$\gamma x_0e^{-\gamma t} = 0$$

$$\implies e^{-\gamma t} = 0 \text{[As } \gamma \text{ and } x_0 \text{ both are constants]}$$

And wow, that is one hard slap to the face. Great equation to solve, hmm (Self-depreciating chuckle).

Please, help me.

Comment: I woul say this function is either increasing or decreasing for t ≥ 0 and gamma ≠ 0. So extreme can only be for t = 0 (= f (0)).

Comment: @georg Yes, And $\gamma > 0$. So, It's always increasing, as pointed out by CoffeeCrow in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what is going on here is that your function $x(t)$ is always increasing (for $\gamma>0$), so there is no finite point at which $\frac{dx}{dt}=0$. This means that the maximum and minimum values must occur at the end points of your interval, $t\in[0,\infty)$.

Since $x(t)$ is increasing, its minimum occurs at $t=0$ and is given by $x(0)=0$. On the other hand, since your interval is infinite, $x(t)$ never actually attains a maximum value. We do however have that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}x(t)=1$, that is $x(t)$ approaches $1$ (but never reaches it in finite time).

Comment: Hmmm, So I was mostly correct. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah absolutely! You found the derivative perfectly, and essentially proved that your $x(t)$ has no stationary points.

Comment: That's good to hear, I feel somewhat proud hehe

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.

> MAXIMUM: When $e^{-\gamma t} = 0 = e^{-\infty} \implies t \to \infty \implies x(\infty) = x_0$

Also, the mimimum value of $1 - e^{-\gamma t}$ is $0$

So, $e^{-\gamma t} = 1 =  e^{0}$

Or

> MINIMUM: $t = 0\implies x(0) = 0$

From the graph below, we find the above results

[image]

Comment: So, The maximum value of my function is $x_0$ and minimum is $0$.

Comment: Yes, assuming that you're considering time to be positive from the reference time, i.e., $t=0$

Comment: Exactly, I'm doing Physics so, yeah, haha